# Calling UserInfo endpoint - IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, access-token

I am wanting to call the UserInfo endpoint, I read this document on [UserInfo Endpoint](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/userinfo.html)... I noticed that you would just call it by `/connect/userinfo`. So when I am running the identity project, I type in the browser `https://localhost:5443/.well-known/openid-configuration` then I see the `userinfo_endpoint`.

[image]

but when I click on it the browser redirects me to a page saying 401

[image]

**I am assuming its because I need to create a bearer token to allow me access to view it, correct? If I am correct, would I have to implement this inside of the Identity project, or API project, or MVC project? (I have three projects for this). Is there any documentation/tutorials on how I would go about getting the `userinfo_endpoint`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user info endpoint returns information about a user, so you need some kind of credentials to identify yourself, so that the server knows information about which user it should return. You need an access token to do that. To get an access token you need to perform an OAuth authorization flow. If you have your identity server available online you can use [OAuth.tools](https://oauth.tools) to perform an OAuth flow. If your server is only on localhost you can still use OAuth.tools to build authorization request and token request (and then use your browser and curl to run them).

Comment: This is very useful thank you! My server is only on localhost, but when I went to OAuth.tools I do not see an option to select for authorization request and one for token request

Comment: Start a new code flow and you will see a form where you can fill parameters for the authorization request. Under the form you will see the whole request. Indeed you will not see the token request, I forgot about that. (the token request is shown only once you finish the authorization request)